# dlib and django. how to integrate and import dlib into django

Tags: python, django, dlib

I am trying to use dlib in my django project. I am using aws ubuntu, but I was not able to use pip dlib, so I compiled directly according davisking instruction to use this PR https://github.com/davisking/dlib/pull/1040. So I was success to install compile dlib and install in my ubuntu.

Now is how to use dlib in django. I tried "import dlib" but its not recognized.

This is how I install dlib and last part of the execution.

```
$ python setup.py install
.....
.....
Processing dlib-19.8.99-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib-19.8.99-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Extracting dlib-19.8.99-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Adding dlib 19.8.99 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dlib-19.8.99-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for dlib==19.8.99
Finished processing dependencies for dlib==19.8.99
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ... 
    'mapwidgets',
    'dlib',
]
```

but it came out with errors below. removing this it still does not recognize "import dlib"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/deploy/somedotcom/somedotcomenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'dlib'
```

How can I start to use dlib in my django project, what is the steps now to import dlib ?

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it seems that Python 3.5 is used instead of 2.7, which dlib was built for. You need to install dlib for the right Python version.

Comment: how do i do that ? do like this ? python3 setup.py install

Comment: @Axil Please try it and report back with the results.

Comment: it doesnt work somehow https://gist.github.com/axilaris/353eaaa61f6b488e0a4b2eb5ac8254e3

Comment: @Axil You need to install setuptools (`pip3 install setuptools`) probably